# SSMS 2016 16.3 (13.0.15700.28) Visual Studio 2015 Shell error

Tags: visual-studio, ssms

SSMS 2016 16.3 will not start displaying "Cannot find one or more components..." message.

Tried repair, uninstall, reinstall, no luck with any of that. Any ideas how to fix this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem with SSMS 2016 16.3 
A solution described in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27998743/microsoft-sql-server-management-studio-opening-error#comment65759379_30570071) has worked for me.

> I just had this issue with SSMS 2016 (rel 16.3). I tried the repair option on the installer which had no effect. I came across the following post which suggested to remove a registry key (HKCU\Software\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio\13.0_Config) which solved the issue for me. Not sure why repair didn't do this if it's a known issue, https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/634911c8-8c85-46c7-aa9d-00c842cefb52/

You also can take a look at other ways suggested in that [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27998743/microsoft-sql-server-management-studio-opening-error) to fix the problem.

Comment: Wow.  I can't remember the last time a suggestion such as simply removing a registry key *actually worked*

Answer (score 0):

Removing this folder solved my problem as well. I did a quick comparison between old and new, some items in the folder appeared to get missing:

- CLR Version => REG_SZ => v4.0.30319
- MsEnvLocation => REG_SZ => C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\msenv.dll
- SetupInitialSqlSettings => REG_SZ => True
- VSIXInstallerLocation => REG_SZ => C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\VSIXInstaller.exe

Maybe this helps anyone fixing the real solution ;) ...